# Why does ping timeout at regular intervals?

Tags: networking

`Request timeout` lines correlate with "the internet is broken" behavior (no web pages load, etc).

- Wired or WiFi makes no difference
- router: Netgear R7000
- modem: SMC Networks D3CM1604
- ISP: Comcast

Power cycling only the modem restores normal function for a day or so, then it reappears.

It appears to be a modem issue. How can I find the root cause?

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=119 time=25.961 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=119 time=27.544 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=11 ttl=119 time=26.326 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=12 ttl=119 time=26.653 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=13 ttl=119 time=25.520 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=14 ttl=119 time=26.044 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=15 ttl=119 time=26.408 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=16 ttl=119 time=27.913 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=17 ttl=119 time=26.010 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=18 ttl=119 time=26.094 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=19 ttl=119 time=28.660 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=20 ttl=119 time=49.911 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=21 ttl=119 time=25.720 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=22 ttl=119 time=26.906 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=23 ttl=119 time=26.084 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 24
Request timeout for icmp_seq 25
Request timeout for icmp_seq 26
Request timeout for icmp_seq 27
Request timeout for icmp_seq 28
Request timeout for icmp_seq 29
Request timeout for icmp_seq 30
Request timeout for icmp_seq 31
Request timeout for icmp_seq 32
Request timeout for icmp_seq 33
Request timeout for icmp_seq 34
Request timeout for icmp_seq 35
Request timeout for icmp_seq 36
Request timeout for icmp_seq 37
Request timeout for icmp_seq 38
Request timeout for icmp_seq 39
Request timeout for icmp_seq 40
Request timeout for icmp_seq 41
Request timeout for icmp_seq 42
Request timeout for icmp_seq 43
Request timeout for icmp_seq 44
Request timeout for icmp_seq 45
Request timeout for icmp_seq 46
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=47 ttl=119 time=26.525 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=48 ttl=119 time=25.628 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=49 ttl=119 time=25.408 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=50 ttl=119 time=25.792 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51 ttl=119 time=26.792 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=52 ttl=119 time=26.603 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=53 ttl=119 time=26.349 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=54 ttl=119 time=27.684 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=55 ttl=119 time=33.048 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=56 ttl=119 time=27.179 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=57 ttl=119 time=25.499 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=58 ttl=119 time=27.939 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=59 ttl=119 time=27.100 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=60 ttl=119 time=27.095 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=61 ttl=119 time=25.687 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=62 ttl=119 time=29.353 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 63
Request timeout for icmp_seq 64
Request timeout for icmp_seq 65
Request timeout for icmp_seq 66
Request timeout for icmp_seq 67
Request timeout for icmp_seq 68
Request timeout for icmp_seq 69
Request timeout for icmp_seq 70
Request timeout for icmp_seq 71
Request timeout for icmp_seq 72
Request timeout for icmp_seq 73
Request timeout for icmp_seq 74
Request timeout for icmp_seq 75
Request timeout for icmp_seq 76
Request timeout for icmp_seq 77
Request timeout for icmp_seq 78
Request timeout for icmp_seq 79
Request timeout for icmp_seq 80
Request timeout for icmp_seq 81
Request timeout for icmp_seq 82
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=83 ttl=119 time=27.984 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=84 ttl=119 time=24.854 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=85 ttl=119 time=25.541 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=86 ttl=119 time=26.787 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=87 ttl=119 time=27.680 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=88 ttl=119 time=26.352 ms
```

Comment: Check the manual for your modem and see how to log in to its management UI and check its various diagnostics and logs and status pages, and see what info you can gather that way.

Comment: Is the modem the DHCP server for the LAN?

Comment: Looks like Google is rate-limiting your ICMP traffic to their systems. this is common to prevent denial of service attacks. it could be at the ISP level, but it looks so uniform, that the google firewall seems like the culprit. can you reproduce these results with multiple servers (at least one non-google) in parallel, and if so, do the timeouts line up for both?